# Impala - maximum number of tuple inserts

Tags: cloudera, impala

What is the max # of tuples you could insert at a time in Impala

```
INSERT INTO sample_table values ('john', 'high',....value 6, value 7, value 8 ......value 25), ('Kim', 'low',... value 6, value 7, value 8 ......value 25),
```

given that a tuple is

```
('john', 'high',....value 6, value 7, value 8 ......value 25)
```

Comment: Do you mean an INSERT with an explicit set of constant values, i.e. an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` statement only, or with any INSERT statement, e.g. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... from other_table`?

Comment: Nope there is no select --- from --- other_table in my query.

Comment: For example consider, `INSERT INTO .... VALUES (tuple_1), (tuple_2), ......(tuple_n)` 
What is the maximum possible value of `n` in this query ? I have inserted 10,000 rows at a time in the past...but it gets slower as the number of records inserted at a time increases. How do I make it faster ? Is there a threshold value to the number of rows/tuples inserted at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

Well. The limit of `n` should depends on how much stack size of the impala frondend's JVM has, since this style of insert statement causes jflex (which impala uses as SQL parser) to recurse at least `n` times, and all the tuples are stored in one deep parse tree. Suppose you've successfully constructed this nasty tree, the next thing shall be serializing it as a thrift message and pass it around. I can only imagine how slowly it could be.

I'd suggest using `LOAD` for large amount of insertions, which transforms to raw file motions, or using `insert into select from`, which internally applies distributed reads and writes over HDFS.